# How to display same margin on second page when printing a page using HTML and CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

This is my code. When I print this page the heading and name are OK on the first sheet, but on the second sheet the heading is not displayed properly.
Is there any other technique to do this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .my-header {
               background: #e3dcf9;
               height: 40px;
               top: 0;
               left: 0;
               position: fixed;
               right: 0;
            }
            thead { display:table-header-group }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="my-header">This is header</div>
        <div style="margin-top:100px;position: relative;">
        <table border="1" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                for($i=1;$i<=150;$i++)
                { 
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
                    <td>Content</td>
                </tr>


            <?php
                }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

mail and print template doesn't support internal css and external css.use inline css for proper result.Don't use internal or external css.